# Получить сообщения из вложенных папок

Tags: pop3, zimbra

Есть и хорошо работает Zimbra 8  по Imap. Решил получить почту по pop3, но столкнулся с проблемой - получаю только письма из папки Входящие, а из всех вложенных папок не получаю. В настройках самой учетки есть только - получать всю почту или получать только новую.

В глобальных нашел только нстройки самого pop3.

Как можно по pop3 получить почту из всех папок, даже из Исходящие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

протокол pop3 не содержит такой сущности, как каталог (folder):

[Of course the other capabilities of IMAP, such as polling an existing connection for newly arrived messages and supporting multiple folders on the server, are not present in POP3.](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt)

но некоторые современные реализации pop3-серверов поддерживают нестандартную возможность «подключаться» к imap-каталогам, [указав их как часть имени пользователя](http://www.afterlogic.com/support/tutorials-mailbee-net/18-pop3-folders.asp):

```
inbox#jdoe
jdoe#inbox
jdoe@domain.com#inbox
```

к каждому каталогу в таком случае нужно подключаться отдельно.