# Как получить список входящих сообщений в почте?

Tags: imap, pop3

У меня в почте >2тыс сообщений в разных папках. В папке входящие у меня штук 10 сообщений, и я постоянно их сортирую в других папки. Теперь по сути задачи.

Как получить сообщения из одной папки Входящие? Пробовал через pop3, но он грузит все данные.

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
                {
                    client.Connect("pop.mail.ru", 995, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                                       client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                    client.Authenticate(login, password);

                        for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var message = client.GetMessage(i);

                        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте через IMAP. И пожалуйста укажите язык программирования - желательно и в тексте вопроса и в метках.

Comment: И вот еще есть немного похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490481/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA Возможно вы там найдете решение своей проблемы.